# Cyberpanel how do I change the import size for phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-platform

The default database import size is only 2mb, so thats gotta go. I followed this guide from Cyberpanel to the T but myphpadmin still reflects the default size so I still cant import.

https://cyberpanel.net/docs/4-change-upload-limit-for-phpmyadmin/

Like with this method, i read about finding the php.ini file within the google cloud instance ssh but couldnt find it. Does something else besides whats listed need to be reset before this takes effect?

Answer (score 1):

The solution required updating to the most appropriate PHP version, based on WordPress plugin compatibility, through the Cyberpanel interface. Only after a fresh PHP installation and interfacing through Cyberpanel could I change the appropriate upload limits- not through the .ini file as normally expected.